# How can I launch the QuickContact action in android 2.1

Tags: android, quickcontact

How can I launch the QuickContact action in android 2.1.
Like the one shown [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GTM_W5mVPTU/S-rk_0rla6I/AAAAAAAAADs/dUw4bDiagO4/s1600/Contacts.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`QuickContactBadge`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html) you'll get that functionality built in. If you want to use it from your own widget you can use [`ContactsContract.QuickContact#showQuickContact`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.QuickContact.html).