# Android custom dialog like 'Quick Contact'

Tags: android, dialog, popupwindow

I want to create a custom dialog like Quick Contact in contact app or the one in official Twitter app. When i click on a button, it will be opened above or below the button.

http://londatiga.net/images/qc-tw.jpg Quick Contact & Twitter

I've read the source code of Contact app but it seems to use internal API. The alternative solution is to extends Dialog class, i can set custom layout, but can't manage to position the dialog. Any solutions for this?

Thanx in advance

Comment: if you want the quick actions: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113106/how-to-make-twitter-app-style-quick-actions-on-android  if you want the quick contact popup: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168115/how-can-i-launch-the-quickcontact-action-in-android-2-1/3168363#3168363

Comment: Thanx a lot Qberticus, thats excatly as i want..will make a try..:-)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this project [NewQuickAction3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

The default orientation is vertical, so it will looks much different as you wish. You need to change the orientation in `ExampleActivity` from `VERTICAL` to `HORIZONTAL`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this project [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)

It have exactly what you need. You just have to merge it in your project and call right activity, it is very easy. There is also GreenDroid demo app on the market, it is called [GDCatalog](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog&feature=search_result) so you can test some of the features. And I think that there is a python script that merge GreenDroid in to your app for you. QuickAction is the demo in the app that you are looking for. It is very good looking too.